# "lazily" unmount last mounted fs?

Tags: linux, mount

Is there a way to unmount the last mounted filesystem without doing `umount <dev>`?

I ask because I'm getting tired of doing `mount` to get the device when all I **could** do is just unmount the last filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you know the mountpoint, so you can just do `umount /mnt/point`.

I don't know of an "unmount last filesystem" option, but personally, it sounds a bit risky. You could do something like

```
fs='/dev/sda1'
mount $fs /mnt/point
.
.
.
umount $fs
```

If that makes your life any easier.

Answer (score 1):

I have never tried this, but you might want to test it. The `tune2fs` utility gives the last mount time for a file system, if run with the `-l` flag. You can then write a script to list all the `last mount time` field for all your mount points and then unmount the latest one.

Partial output from tune2fs

```
    root@localhost:/# tune2fs -l /dev/sda1  | grep -i time
    Last mount time:          Tue Mar  5 17:40:36 2013
    Last write time:          Mon Feb  4 11:53:20 2013
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5426818/ordering-of-proc-mounts-and-etc-mtab), `/proc/mounts` contains a list of filesystems in mounted order.  Therefore you could do

```
umount `tail -1 /proc/mounts | cut -f2 -d' '`
```